# Unable to build android module in flutter 2.5.3 after add dependency

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Configure project :path_provider_android Evaluating project ':path_provider_android' using build file 'C:\Users\yazad\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.9\android\build.gradle'.

Comment: Please specify what dependency you added, flutter version you are using and if possible, the error you are getting. Remember to use well the WYSIWYG editor to format the content where it needs be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command `flutter pub cache repair`

Comment: not working already try .when try build without and dependency project run fine and android module also open up but when dependency were add it kind through error

Comment: Please share your logcat